# Call angular service function after ng-click is fired

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a module named "request" and "purchase order". The request can view and edit purchase orders that have been made. And the purchase order module made to also manage purchase orders.

Basically, it is the same stuff but can be accessed either from request or purchase orders. So, instead copy paste all the code from purchase orders, I decided to pass the id, and then call the Purchase Order Ctrl. Then I created a service to pass the ID, since i searched that using $broadcast is not a good practice.

The ID can be passed successfully, however, Why does the angular service will only be executed once after the ng-click is fired?

Here is my service code

```
.service('passID', function () {
    var id = null;
    var setID = function(passed_id) {
        id = passed_id;
    };

    var getID = function(){
        return id;
    };

    return {
        setID: setID,
        getID: getID
    };
})
```

here is the function in my request controller

```
var vm          = this;
vm.createModule = createModule;

function createModule(type,id){
    vm.state = null;
    switch(type){
        case "PurchaseOrder":
            vm.state = type;
            passID.setID(id);
        break;
    }
}
```

and here is the code inside my purchase order controller

```
if(passID.getID() != null){
    vm.id = passID.getID();
    console.log(vm.id);
}
```

here is the request view file

```
 <li role="menuitem"><a href="" ng-click="vm.createModule('PurchaseOrder',item.id)">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Create Purchase Order </a>
 </li>

 <div ng-controller="customerPurchaseOrderCtrl" ng-if="vm.state == 'PurchaseOrder'">
    <span ng-include="'app_view/modules/ship/purchase_order/customer/form.html'" ></span>
</div>
```

Once the page has been loaded, and then i fire the `ng-click` function, it works well, it runs the `console.log(vm.id)`. But when I click on another request data, it doesn't work anymore. The `console.log` is not running.

What am I doing wrong here? thank you :)

Comment: For that particular example It seems correct. Can you provide some code where you are trying to click on another request data?

Comment: You are calling `vm.createModule` in html.Where it is assign to this?

Comment: in your controller bind createModule to vm like, `var vm = this; vm.createModule = createModule;`

Comment: You need to post a bit more than just code fragments. Guessing, I would be looking for a missing `$scope.$digest()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is probably not public in a sense you didn't expose it do the VIEW either via $scope or using controller alias. Since you are using controller alias vm. In your controller you could bind your createModule to controller's `this` reference, like:

```
//at the beginnning of controller definition
var vm = this;
vm.createModule = createModule
```

this way you can access createModule function of vm from VIEW, another method would be to bind createModule to scope which is almost similar to this method except you bind your method on scope and scope is by default available in VIEW.

Comment: Sir, i have defined it before. that is why It can work once, but when I click another data, the service won't run anymore